# How do I maintain transparency in an image from a Http Handler when using Graphics.DrawImage?

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, gdi+, httphandler

I've got a series of GIFs that I need to crop on the fly, I'm using a HTTP Handler in C# so I can better encapsulate the code - provide caching for the result etc.

Currently, when I draw the existing image to a new `Image` via the `Graphics` object all the transparency is lost.

I've tried various techniques to try and maintain the transparency, but to no avail.

Things I've tried:

- Using the `MakeTransparent (Color)` method call
- Using the `ImageAttriutes` with a combination of `ColorMap` and `SetColorKey`

I don't really want to start using unsafe operators or Win32 calls.

Any ideas?

Comment: Off topic coment - nice to see another Southampton dev! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to have been answered already [How do you Draw Transparent Image using System.Drawing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189392/how-do-you-draw-transparent-image-using-systemdrawing)

Answer (score 0):

When I have used transparency I've always used `Bitmap`. I.e.

```
System.Drawing.Image SourceImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile("the.gif");
System.Drawing.Bitmap NewImage = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(SourceImage);
// Do Processing
NewImage.MakeTransparent();
// Store changes
NewImage.Save(..., System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
```

Of course if you cannot move away from the `Graphics` object then that may not be of much use.