# How to make a System.Drawing.Image semitransparent?

Tags: .net, image, graphics, transparency, alpha

`System.Drawing.Graphics.DrawImage` pastes one image on another. But I couldn't find a transparency option.

I have already drawn everything I want in the image, I only want to make it translucent (alpha-transparency)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/189392/how-do-you-draw-transparent-image-using-system-drawing

Comment: @Mitch Wheat - that question is specific to GIFs

Comment: GIFs don't have semi-transparency. I am talking about PNGs here

Comment: Post the code that you are using and give us some details about the images you are looking to combine and we can probably help.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is no "transparency" option because what you're trying to do is called Alpha Blending.

```
public static class BitmapExtensions
{
    public static Image SetOpacity(this Image image, float opacity)
    {
        var colorMatrix = new ColorMatrix();
        colorMatrix.Matrix33 = opacity;
        var imageAttributes = new ImageAttributes();
        imageAttributes.SetColorMatrix(
            colorMatrix,
            ColorMatrixFlag.Default,
            ColorAdjustType.Bitmap);
        var output = new Bitmap(image.Width, image.Height);
        using (var gfx = Graphics.FromImage(output))
        {
            gfx.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
            gfx.DrawImage(
                image,
                new Rectangle(0, 0, image.Width, image.Height),
                0,
                0,
                image.Width,
                image.Height,
                GraphicsUnit.Pixel,
                imageAttributes);
        }
        return output;
    }
}
```

[Alpha Blending](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/alphafx.aspx)

Comment: [ColorMatrix](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.colormatrix(v=vs.110).aspx) + [ImageAttributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.imageattributes(v=vs.110).aspx) + [SmoothingMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z714w2y9(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

```
private Image GetTransparentImage(Image image, int alpha)
{
    Bitmap output = new Bitmap(image);

    for (int x = 0; x < output.Width; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < output.Height; y++)
        {
            Color color = output.GetPixel(x, y);
            output.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(alpha, color.R, color.G, color.B));
        }
    }

    return output;
}
```

Comment: This is not a good way to draw an image. Doing it pixel by pixel is going to be terrible for performance.

Answer (score -1):

I copied an answer from the link Mitch provided that I think will work for me:

```
public static Bitmap SetOpacity(this Bitmap bitmap, int alpha)
{
    var output = new Bitmap(bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height);
    foreach (var i in Enumerable.Range(0, output.Palette.Entries.Length))
    {
        var color = output.Palette.Entries[i];
        output.Palette.Entries[i] =
            Color.FromArgb(alpha, color.R, color.G, color.B);
    }
    BitmapData src = bitmap.LockBits(
        new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height),
        ImageLockMode.ReadOnly,
        bitmap.PixelFormat);
    BitmapData dst = output.LockBits(
        new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height),
        ImageLockMode.WriteOnly,
        output.PixelFormat);
    bitmap.UnlockBits(src);
    output.UnlockBits(dst);
    return output;
}
```